# Calculating the Standard Deviation by category using Python

Tags: python

I have a datset with Scores and Categories and I would like to calculate the Standard Deviation of these scores, per category. The data look something like this:

```
Category    Score    
AAAA        1
AAAA        3
AAAA        1
BBBB        1
BBBB        100
BBBB        159
CCCC        -10
CCCC        9
```

What I would then like is the Standard Deviation of each Category. I know that with numpy I can use the following:

```
numpy.std(a)
```

But the example I can find only have this relating to a list and not a range of different categories in a DataFame.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use pandas in these types of work, as the answer suggested.

Comment: This one should be moved to stack-overflow. There's no `science` stuff here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["AA", 1], ["AA", 3], ["BB", 3], ["CC", 5], ["BB", 2], ["AA", -1]])
df.columns = ["Category", "Score"]
print df.groupby("Category").apply(np.std)
```

Comment: Amazing. Great answer!

Comment: I think we can get rid of `.apply()` - `df.groupby("Category").std(ddof=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight variation in the input data. I have more than one column, so how to give command to pick a specific column for the calculation of std deviation.

Comment: adapting @MaxU's comment, you can do column access on the groupby object as if it was a dataframe. So df.groupby('Category')['specific_column'].std(ddof=0) would work